# Assertion thrown in Release but not debug - necessarily a compiler bug?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, release

This is not a specific question about my code but a more high level question.

I have C++ code that compiles in Release and Debug mode (both with assertions turned on)

There is no code in the library that checks for Debug etc (via prerocsssor definitions or macros).

Running in debug mode doesn't cause any assertions. Running in Release or RelWithDebInfo throws an assertition every time.

Does this necessarily mean that there is a bug in the MSVC compiler/optimiser? Also, more generally: does a difference in program behaviour between Release and Debug always constitute a bug in the compiler.

Note: clang run this code fine without throwing assertions in Release and Debug.

Comment: It is difficult to say without an example, it could be a problem related to an uninitialized variable. or something else entirely. Are you compiling your code with the highest warning level set in Visual Studio?

Comment: If you run the RelWithDebInfo in a debugger (possible since you have debug information), where does the assertion happen? And having something work using some compiler or build configurations, but not in others is often more an indicator that you do something that leads to *undefined behavior* than a bug in the compiler or library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of thing is almost never a compiler bug. If you have code that overwrites data because of a stray pointer, when you compile with different options it can overwrite different data, with vastly different results.